# Apache HttpClient AD FS and SAML assertions

Tags: java, httpclient, saml, adfs

I am having trouble getting Apache HttpClient 4 to follow SiteMinder AD FS 2.0 authentication through a RADIUS server (securID).  I've gotten it to work without the AD FS, but AD FS sends back an autopost with a SAML assertion.  I try to pull the parameters myself and post again, but it sends back a message saying something is wrong.  The error message is very generic.

The only thing I can see obviously different between how HttpClient works and a browser is the referer is not set during redirects by HttpClient.  When watching a browser follow redirects (using Fiddler), the referer header parameter is always set as the previous location.  With HttpClient, the referer is not.

Has anyone used Apache HttpClient 4 to authenticate to a SAML / AD FS 2.0 server?  Sample code?  thanks